# PostgresSQL connection refused on docker container in same server

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have postgresSQL database running docker on server when i spin up another container for django app and trying to connect postgress getting connection error. any idea?

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 6545 failed: Connection refused
> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
> connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 6545 failed: Cannot assign requested address
> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

DB docker file

```
container_name: pg-docker
ports:
  - "6545:5432"
volumes:
  - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
networks:
  - default
```

Django docker file

```
version: "3.9"
services:
django_api:
  build:
    context: ./app
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  container_name: api-dev
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  ports:
    - 8000:8000
  networks:
    - default
```

Comment: Postgres is not running on localhost relative to your django container. Localhost for django means its own container. If you want to connect to PSQL you need to make sure both containers use the same network. If they do, you can easily use the container name (the docker DNS will automatically fetch an IP address based on that name).
Make sure to connect to the right port on the PSQL container as well. I believe the default/standard is 5432.

Comment: @JustLudo İ also added network but same problem.

Comment: Did you read the rest of the description? Your code does not reflect you attempting to connect to postgres. It's prob. somewhere in your django configuration file, best include that as well in here.

Answer (score 1):

As @JustLudo said in the Comments, you have to address postgres with the container name "pg-docker". Localhost would be your django container.
In general, if you use multiple docker containers you should not use localhost. Instead treat every container as a standalone server and address via DNS / container_name.